# How to get DynamoDB from DynamoDB local creation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

Trying to write integration test for my logic, using recommended way to launch dynamoDB local:

```
            final String port = getAvailablePort();
            this.server = ServerRunner.createServerFromCommandLineArgs(new String[] { "-inMemory", "-port", port });
            server.start();

            amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                    // we can use any region here
                    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:" + port, "us-west-2")).build();
```

I am planning to use com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB in my production code to read/write from dynamo.  I am looking to reuse some production dynamo-write code to setup testing data, hence, I will need com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB object. However dynamo local setup above only give com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB, any clue/suggestion on how to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of `DynamoDB` from a `AmazonDynamoDB` using [this constructor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/DynamoDB.html#DynamoDB-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB-) which has a signature of `DynamoDB(AmazonDynamoDB client)`.

Comment: I did it by:                  new DynamoDB(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                                    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-east-1"))
                            .build());